# changes are reflected from work directory but not from webapps in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

We are working on customizing BI 4 applications.
We are facing two issues:

a) Customization is happening if we place our changes in work folder.
When we tried to make those changes only in webapps , its not reflecting

b) We have added our jar to MANIFEST file of webapp but changes are not reflected.
If we directly place the class files in WEB-INF/classes folder under work , changes rae reflected.

Please let us know if anyone has faced these issues.
Thanks.

Comment: We have got explanation for first issue.Work is cache folder for tomcat and is rebuilt once deleted.After deleting work folder , new folders were created as similar to webapps folder.

Comment: Please let us know if any suggestions for second issue